# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - How do I get a client's IP Address?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, httpcontext, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a Razor Page Web Application and am logging users' IP addresses. For some reason it is returning an IP address but not the client's user IP Address. I believe it may be returning the IP from the server?

**Note:** *I have added user logging in all of the other ASP.NET Web Forms applications and it's logging the correct IPs. This is our only ASP.NET Core application and it's returning a different IP.*

Am I missing something in the ConfigureServices method that's preventing it from getting the users' ip address?

**My code from the ConfigureServices method in the startup class:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddAntiforgery(option =>
        {
            option.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN";
            option.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
        });
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
    }
```

**I am also calling the UserForwardedHeaders method in the Configure method as such:**

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

**I am using RemoteIPAddress when retrieving the IP Address:**

```
 HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()
```

Comment: What makes you believe it is returning the ip address of the server vs what you expect?

Comment: Because it's logging a completely different IP for me and my other teammate than our local machine's IP when we navigate the website. For instance, it's logging 10.01.01.12 (not the real IP) for both of us. However it logs different IPs for different users but they're not their local machines. I have added logging on all of ASP.NET website and it's logging the correct IP address. However, this is our only ASP.Core application in production and it's the only one logging different IPs.

Comment: Where are you using the code to getting IpAddress??

Comment: @Hadi I am using it in my IActionResult OnGet() method in the cshtml.cs pages

Comment: You don't have a different proxy setup like a scanning/anti-virus proxy in between? If you are getting different ips per user but they are not correct then I guess either something is nat-ing between browser and server or something is inserting/overwriting the X-Forwarded-For header. Perhaps create an action that dumps the headers to a page and see what is arriving?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ipAddr = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

This will return `{::1}` when you execute the code at local. After deployment to the Test or Production server, it will get your client's IP

```
var deviceName = Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).HostName;
```

It is for finding the Computer Name for the intranet application.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did in .NET Core 2.1 ASP.NET MVC Application

```
public static string GetIpAddressFromHttpRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest)
{
  string ipAddressString = string.Empty;
  if (httpRequest == null)
  {
    return ipAddressString;
  }
  if (httpRequest.Headers != null && httpRequest.Headers.Count > 0)
  {
    if (httpRequest.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-For") == true)
    {
      string headerXForwardedFor = httpRequest.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerXForwardedFor) == false)
      {
        string xForwardedForIpAddress = headerXForwardedFor.Split(':')[0];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xForwardedForIpAddress) == false)
        {
          ipAddressString = xForwardedForIpAddress;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if (httpRequest.HttpContext == null ||
       httpRequest.HttpContext.Connection == null ||
       httpRequest.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress == null)
  {
       ipAddressString = httpRequest.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
  }
  return ipAddressString;
}
```

My application working good in Google Chrome. I did not test in another browsers.